# Direct comparison of Go interface{} to built-in types: Why does this work?

Tags: go, types, casting

Why does the following Go code work?

That is, since the types of `f` and `b` are `interface{}` (and not any of `bool`, `int` or `string`), how is it possible for me to get away with *not* casting or type-asserting `f` and `b` in each of the three `if` statements?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func foop(p map[string]interface{}) {
    p["foo"] = true
}

func barp(p map[string]interface{}) {
    p["bar"] = 17
}

func foop2(p map[string]interface{}) {
    p["foo"] = "blah"
}

func main() {
    p := make(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", p)

    foop(p)
    barp(p)
    f := p["foo"]
    b := p["bar"]
    fmt.Printf("f: %T\n", f)
    if f == true {
        fmt.Println("ok")
    }
    fmt.Printf("b: %T\n", b)
    if b == 17 {
        fmt.Println("ok")
    }

    foop2(p)
    f = p["foo"]
    if f == "blah" {
        fmt.Println("ok")
    }
    fmt.Printf("f: %T\n", f)
    fmt.Printf("f: %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(f))
}
```

(Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/kPi25yW6tF)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with most Go language questions, the answer is in the [Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec), specifically the section on [Comparison Operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators).

> A value x of non-interface type X and a value t of interface type T are comparable when values of type X are comparable and X implements T. They are equal if t's dynamic type is identical to X and t's dynamic value is equal to x.